# C# using Split() with Lists?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winapi, list, split

I am trying to split a string into a list of values, by splitting it by a given character. I need it to be a list rather than an array because the number of values can change. How would I go about doing this?

For example:

```
String s = "red, green, blue, unicorn";
```

would become a list where the element at index 0 is red, then 1 is green, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your string is comma delimited:

```
var str = "this, is, a, list, of, stuff";
var list = 
      str
        .Split(',')
        //.Select(s => s.Trim()) //maybe a good idea?
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Ah.There's a question... `string.Split` returns an array (or `IEnumerable<string>`) which means you can use linq extension methods on it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2006/10/29/technical-links-to-linq.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`String.Split[]` returns `string[]`. The array will hold however many elements the string had. Can't you use that? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> > I have to split a string into a list because i dont know how many values the list is going to have.

I am not sure why you think you need a list to know how many values are returned by Split?

The call to Split does tell you how many values it finds.

For Example:

```
using System;

namespace SampleApplication
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var input = "one,two,three,four,five,six";

            string [] words = input.Split(',');

            Console.WriteLine("Number of Words: {0}", words.Length);

            foreach (object value in words)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code produces this output:

```
C:\temp>test
Number of Words: 6
one
two
three
four
five
six

C:\temp>
```